# apt-get update not working

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to install haproxy to my Debian Server. I have followed the instructions as below:

> - create a new file called `backports.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
> - Add the follwing to the file: `deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian wheezy­backports main`
> - run: `apt­-get update`
> - run: `apt-get install haproxy`

The problem is that when I do the `update` it tells me that:

```
Err http://cdn.debian.net wheezy­backports/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy­backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is there a way to get round this? (I'm new to Linux so I apologise if this has an easy/obvious answer). I've tried searching but can't seem to see anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the hyphen in `wheezy-backports`:

```
 deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian wheezy­-backports main
```

See [the backports website](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) for the complete instructions.

Comment: cheers, that fixed it. It just shows that blindly copying and pasting from websites doesn't always work.